# Binary in invalid after uploading into iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am uploading one of my application into the **App Store**. As after successful uploading application into store, application status will change to **"ITC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.invalidBinary"** or **"This Build is invalid."**.

As I research why its happening, and come to know this is becuase of wrong naming covensatin of Icon file. So I make a neccessary changes into my icon file and re-upload the application, but still getting same issue.

If anybody knows the solution, then help me to out from this issue.

Comment: Are you using Swift in your application?

Comment: Make sure your app icons don't have any Alpha Channels in them, such as transparency. Even if you don't think there is any, there's a chance they may be pointlessly there.

Comment: Did you try to try to validate your build when submitting through the project organizer in xcode?

Comment: Hey I am using some which is in swift.